# UINavigationController's navigation bar wont shrink when in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, landscape

My navigation controller's navigation bar won't change the height when rotated to landscape.
[image]

see it stays at 44 pixels instead of 34 i think.

What do i do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add your navigation controller directly as a subview to your window, otherwise this doesn't work automatically. (It is not necessary to change the frame of your navigation bar manually.)

The `-[application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method of your `AppDelegate` should contain something like

```
[window addSubview:self.yourNavController.view];
```

To get an example where this works automatically, you can also create a new navigation-based app in XCode and add an implementation for the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of the RootViewController that always returns YES.

Answer (score -1):

During the autoRotation method of your class, change the frame of your navBar like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,32);
    }
    else if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,44);
    }
    else
    {
         assert(false);
    }
}
```